# RecyclerView OnScrollStateChanged() and onScrolled()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My question is, can We call `RecyclerView`'s `onScrolled()` Method from `onScrollStateChanged()` method. The reason is I want to check two conditions. If `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING` is true only then check if the user has scrolled down. Is there any other way to check Both of them?

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {

              // Now I have to check if the user has scrolled down or up.  

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);


        }
    });
```

Comment: what ever you are trying to achieve can be done in onscrillstatechanged itself. provide some more details so that i can tell how to do that

Comment: Done. When newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING, I want to check if user has scrolled down or not.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

From `onScrolled` method you can set a boolean flag 'isScrolledDown' by checking if `dy` is less than 0 to know that user scrolled down. Then whenever the scroll state is `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING` and `isScrolledDown` is true then do the operation you want.

```java
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        private boolean isScrolledDown = false;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING && isScrolledDown) {

              // Do something...

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            isScrolledDown = dy < 0;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Detect start scroll and end scroll in recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454609/detect-start-scroll-and-end-scroll-in-recyclerview/33454785)

Answer (score 0):

you may start by declaring these two variable outside your listener

```
//chose appropriate initial values
  var updatedRange = Range(...) 
  var lastVisibilityRange = Range(...)
```

then in the listener callback you'll have something like this:

```
override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

                    val first = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                    val last = manager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
                    lastVisibilityRange = updatedRange
                    updatedRange = Range(first , last)

                    //or you can even call this section in onScrollStateChanged 
                    if (updatedRange.lower <= lastVisibilityRange.lower) {
                        //has scrolled up
                    } else {
                        //has scrolled down
                    }

                }
```

the code hasn't been tested, you may make it more reactive by throwing a `LiveData` in there, feel free to let me know if this is not what you're looking for, hope this will help or point you in the right direction, have a good day y'all.