# android recyclerview scrollToPosition problem

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll

I want recyclerview to start on line 10. Where am I making a mistake. Could it be something related to NestedScrollView? Could it be something related to NestedScrollView?

KuranFragment.java

```
 ayetlerAdapter = new AyetlerAdapter(getContext(),ayetlerList,veri);

 recyclerView.scrollToPosition(10);

 recyclerView.setAdapter(ayetlerAdapter);
```

fragment_kuran.xml

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:background="@drawable/sureheader2"
            android:id="@+id/sureAd"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sureAd"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Switch
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/switchTR"
                android:text="TR"/>
            <Switch
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/switchAR"
                android:text="AR"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/rvAyetler" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I want recyclerview to start on line 10 ? can you explain it bit more.

Comment: I want scroll to start automatically from line 10 when recyclerview is loaded

Comment: Have a look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455266/5110595)

Comment: Did you tried first to set adapter and than to scroll to position?
`recyclerView.setAdapter(ayetlerAdapter);
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(10);`

Comment: yes i tried but again not

Comment: do you use LinearLayoutManager for recycler?

Comment: yes. I use RecyclerView.LayoutManager. 
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false);

Comment: Add below line after notifyDataSetChanged()

recyclerView.scrollToPosition(10);

becoz initially there is no data so recyclerview will not scroll to given position
but after network call / any Adapter will be notified

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            if (linearLayoutManager != null) {

```
            linearLayoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
            linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, 0);
        }
```