# recyclerview add scrollListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with Horizontal `LinearLayoutManager`.
I would like to check `ScrollListener`. 
My goal is to check these steps:

1. Check when `RecyclerView` start scroll
2. Check when `RecyclerView` end scroll
3. Check when `RecyclerView`'s scroll is in center position

Here is a my `RecyclerView` code with `LinearLayoutManager`.

```
LinearLayoutManager horizontalManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        horizontalManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        viewHolderStory.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(horizontalManager);
        viewHolderStory.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new PaddingItemDecoration((Activity) context));
        viewHolderStory.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        viewHolderStory.recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            }
        });
        viewHolderStory.recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Is any way to add validation on my addOnScrollListener method?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if(newState==RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
                    /// User Stops Scroll
                 }
                if(newState==RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING){
                 /// User Starts Scroll
              }
            }
```

You can find more from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455266/3967525).

Answer (score 0):

You can compute this with `computeVerticalScrollExtent()` , `computeVerticalScrollOffset()` and `computeVerticalScrollRange()`

if your recyler view is horizontal, these functions have a horizontal counterpart

full code :

```
viewHolderStory.recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        int extent = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollExtent();
        int offset = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset();
        int range = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange();

        if(offset == 0){
            //fire when recycler view hit top
            Log.i("myTag", "onScrolled: top");
        }
        else if(offset + extent == range){
            //fire when recycler view hit bottom
            Log.i("myTag", "onScrolled: bottom");
        }
        else {
            //fire the rest of the time
            Log.i("myTag", "onScrolled: middle");
        }
    }
});
```