# detect scrolling inside RecyclerView item / OnBindViewHolder

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Is it possible to detect Recyclerview scrolling inside:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

}
```

?

Maybe with a workaround? But **without** using `notifyItemChanged(pos)` and `notifyDataSetChanged()`

I need it to be able to detect when a video is fully visible and then start it if it is and stop when it's not fully visible any more

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455266/14884388. If its not what you are looking for we can further work around.

Comment: This is how you set scroll listener in activity/fragement where you initialize RecycleView but I need to detect scroll from within item

Comment: May I ask why you can't use the notify methods?

Comment: Because it reloads the whole item and the video would start from beginning again, besides it's just overkill in general

Comment: `onBindViewHolder` can get call multiple times . The solution to your problem is to put a scrolllistener on the `RecyclerView` and check for visible item and then provide  callback to adapter .

Comment: I don't understand it, can you show example for "onBindViewHolder can get call multiple times"? Or the whole process?